# Matching a phone number at the end of a string with `regex`, and return both parts

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have a bunch of lines like the following:

```
Name1 Surname1         +44 (020) 1234 5678 
Name2 Name2 Surname2   +39 (051) 12.34.56
Surname3, Name3      -     (555) 123-456-789
Surname4, Name4 Name4       123 - 456.78.90
```

and I would like to identify and return the names and the numbers that they contain. For instance, I would like to return:

1. `Name1 Surname1         +44 (020) 1234 5678`

   - name: `Name1 Surname1`
   - number: `+44 (020) 1234 5678`
2. `Name2 Name2 Surname2   +39 (051) 12.34.56`

   - name: `Name2 Name2 Surname2`
   - number: `+39 (051) 12.34.56`
3. `Surname3, Name3      -     (555) 123-456-789`

   - name: `Surname3, Name3      -`
   - number: `(555) 123-456-789`
4. `Surname4, Name4 Name4       123 - 456.78.90`

   - name: `Surname4, Name4 Name4`
   - number: `123 - 456.78.90`

I'm using *Java* `regex` and, so far, I came up to the following pattern:

```
\A(.*)\s+(\+?\s*\d+([.-\s]*(\d+|\(\d+\)))+)\z
```

If `line` is any of above lines, the code to match the pattern is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\\s+(\\+?\\s*\\d+([.-\\s]*(\\d+|\\(\\d+\\)))+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + pattern.group(1));
    System.out.println("Number: " + pattern.group(2));
}
```

Unfortunately, on any `line` (`Name1 Surname1         +44 (020) 1234 5678`, for instance) it returns the following:

```
Name: Name1 Surname1         +44 (020) 1234
Number: 5678
```

I think that the reason for this result is the `regex` being too greedy, but I don't understand how to modify its behaviour.

Can anyone please correct the pattern and explain me the solution in simple terms? I read a few tutorial without understanding what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I've been beaten to the punch by @ClasG (nice one), but I can offer a modified version of your own regex. I got: `^(.*?)\s+(\+?\s*((\d+|\(\d+\))[-.\s]*)+)$`

Comment: Actually, I just realised that a phone number may be simply started by a digit (added example 4 to reflect that case) and the symbol to match end of line is missing, so the proper regex should be:
`^(.*?)\s*((?:\+|\(|\d)[-\d(). ]*)$`, where:
`^` beginning of line
`(.*?)` a group matching any string (possibly empty) not matched by the following
`\s*` a (possibly empty) separator
`( ... )` another group whose content is:
`(?:\+|\(|\d)` advance until you match a `+`, a `(` or `0..9`
`[ .-\d)(]*` any string composed by a ` `, `.`, `-`, `0..9`, `(`, `(`

Comment: Last comment, I promise! I've noticed that it's useful to have `\b` just before the number: `^(.*?)\s*\b((?:\+|\(|\d)[-\d(). ]+)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest I can think of right now would be

```
^(.*?)\s*((?:\+|\()[-\d(). ]*)
```

It captures everything **up to** the spaces preceding a `+` or a `(`. Then it captures everything after that (being digits, hyphens, parentheses, dots or spaces) to a second group.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hP4wP6/1).

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks! 
I'm having a look to the website you liked and it provides a very good explanation.

Comment: Glad to help. I just noticed that the hyphen in the third example get captured as part of the name. You can avoid that by using `^(.*?)[-\s]*((?:\+|\()[-\d(). ]*)$` (allowing for space **or** hyphen between the parts. [See here](https://regex101.com/r/hP4wP6/2).

Comment: That's fine, thanks! I have some other code that takes care of the name part!

Comment: I think your regex also misses the final `$` (and I couldn't add it by myself)...

Comment: It's there in the second one (in my comment). But it really isn't necessary since the final capture is greedy, it'll capture everything up to EOL.